# About Timezone. From one to another timezone

Tags: php, timezone

If i use

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
?>
```

as default timezone to a page of my website.
And if I `echo` this on this page:
`echo date_default_timezone_get()." ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`.
A user from `America/Los_Angeles` will find the date?

Comment: Why don't you use UTC as default timezone and convert that in client side. In that way every user will get the time in their local time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built-in to PHP that can detect the client's time zone.  Instead, you'll need to [detect the user's time zone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22625076/634824).  You can then send that string to the server, and pass it into PHP's various time zone functions.